# How kubernetes maintains different api version resource?

Tags: kubernetes, api-design, autoscaling

Kubernetes versions:

v1.15.2

Scenario shows：

kubernetes v1.15.2 have added some new api versions,for example, the `autoscaling/v2beta2` in the autoscaling group. But after read the HorizontalController structure in kubernetes code `src\k8s.io\kubernetes\pkg\controller\podautoscaler\`, All the members in HorizontalController is `autoscaling/v1`.

```
type HorizontalController struct {
    scaleNamespacer scaleclient.ScalesGetter                                ==> autoscaling/v1
    hpaNamespacer   autoscalingclient.HorizontalPodAutoscalersGetter        ==> autoscaling/v1
    mapper          apimeta.RESTMapper

    replicaCalc   *ReplicaCalculator
    eventRecorder record.EventRecorder

    downscaleStabilisationWindow time.Duration

    // hpaLister is able to list/get HPAs from the shared cache from the informer passed in to
    // NewHorizontalController.
    hpaLister       autoscalinglisters.HorizontalPodAutoscalerLister        ==> autoscaling/v1
    hpaListerSynced cache.InformerSynced                                    ==> autoscaling/v1

    // podLister is able to list/get Pods from the shared cache from the informer passed in to
    // NewHorizontalController.
    podLister       corelisters.PodLister
    podListerSynced cache.InformerSynced

    // Controllers that need to be synced
    queue workqueue.RateLimitingInterface

    // Latest unstabilized recommendations for each autoscaler.
    recommendations map[string][]timestampedRecommendation
}
```

So how kubernetes maintans the autoscaling/v2beta2 resources with HorizontalController?

Answer (score 0):

In the official kubernetes [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/run-application/horizontal-pod-autoscale/#api-object) You can find following information:

> ### API Object
>
> The Horizontal Pod Autoscaler is an API resource in the Kubernetes  `autoscaling`  API group. The current stable version, which only includes support for CPU autoscaling, can be found in the  `autoscaling/v1`  API version.
>
> The beta version, which includes support for scaling on memory and custom metrics, can be found in  `autoscaling/v2beta2`. The new fields introduced in  `autoscaling/v2beta2`  are preserved as annotations when working with  `autoscaling/v1`.
>
> More details about the API object can be found at  [HorizontalPodAutoscaler Object](https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/design-proposals/autoscaling/horizontal-pod-autoscaler.md#horizontalpodautoscaler-object).

Also according to kubernetes documentation about [API overview](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/using-api/api-overview/) under API versioning:

> ### API versioning
>
> To eliminate fields or restructure resource representations,
>   Kubernetes supports multiple API versions, each at a different API
>   path. For example:  `/api/v1`  or  `/apis/extensions/v1beta1`.
>
> The version is set at the API level rather than at the resource or
>   field level to:
>
> - Ensure that the API presents a clear and consistent view of system resources and behavior.
> - Enable control access to end-of-life and/or experimental APIs.
>
> The JSON and Protobuf serialization schemas follow the same guidelines
>   for schema changes. The following descriptions cover both formats.

---

So You can find all apis versions for `autoscaling` like `v2beta2` under [kubernetes/pkg/apis/autoscaling/](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/tree/master/pkg/apis/autoscaling) .

For example using `HTTP GET` would be like this: `GET /apis/autoscaling/v2beta2`